# TFS Update 2 Code Coverage is missing

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage, tfsbuild

We have upgraded to TFS Update 2 release management recently. Enabled code coverage in Visual Studio Test as show below.

[image]

Build runs successfully and show test cases execution result.

[image]

But I dont see Code Coverage information. Do we need any other configuration?

UPDATE:
I tries detaching the collection, but no luck.

Comment: TFS Update 2 Code Coverage is missing， is it worked with your prior  version TFS ? If it worked which version of the TFS.  Did you use nunit test?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT is it worked with your prior version TFS ?. No, We had TFS web based release update 1 then upgraded to TFS Update 2. We are using mstest.

Comment: Can you share the settings in your settings file?

Answer (score 0):

In your build definition you specify using .runsettings file for Code Coverage. So when Code Coverage is ran it loads the collectionscodecoverage.runsettings file and returns result depending on whats in it. Most likely .runsettings file is not correct.

1. You can collect Code Coverage without having a settings file. Just leave the "Run Settings File" option empty on build definition.
2. To validate that your .runsettings file is correct - run Code Coverage locally from Visual Studio having .runsettings file set as default test settings file. See details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx).

Another possible problem addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288239/tfs-2015-code-coverage-is-not-displaying) post.