# TFS 2015 Code Coverage is not displaying

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage, tfs-2015, alm

I'm using TFS 2015 (Update 2.1) build process and everything is working as expected except the code coverage part.

Build with VS Test

[image]

(Code coverage enabled)

After successful build:

[image]

(testcase executed without code coverage)

When I checked log, this is what I found:

**Warning: Diagnostic data adapter message: Could not find diagnostic data adapter 'Code Coverage'.  Make sure diagnostic data adapter is installed and try again.**

I have tried

1. De-attaching-attaching collection
2. Re-installed Agent
3. Have included .runsettings file

but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Visual Studio Enterprise on your build server, assuming you have appropriate licensing. Code coverage is an Enterprise feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the coverage report without having to have Visual Studio Enterprise Installed. But you would need "Visual Studio Test Agent". You can download it [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615472&clcid=0x409).

Comment: Did not downvote but you could give a bit more information about Test Agent, how they can provide a test coverage report without Enterprise, and a link to the project page rather than a direct download link to an executable.

Comment: Please link to the page as well.